# not receiving attachments using php pear package on linux based server

Tags: php, attachment, pear, email-attachments

Following is my code for sending attachments.
Any help is useful.`enter code here`
Thanks in advance.

send_attach.php

```
<?php

@include_once 'Mail.php'
@include_once 'Mail/mime.php' ;

$hdrs['email'] = $mime;
$headers['To'] = $work_mail;
$headers['Subject'] = "Application For Job";
$headers['Content-type'] = "text/html; charset=windows-1251";
$headers['MIME-Version'] = "1.0";

$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = '/studylink.txt';
$crlf = "\n";
$hdrs = array(
              'From'    => 'me@here.com',
              'Subject' => 'Test mime message'

               );

$mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file, 'text/plain');

$body = $mime->get();
$body=$mime->get(array('html_charset'=>'windows-1251','text_charset'=>'windows-1251','head_charset'=>'windows-1251'));
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

@$mail =& Mail::factory('mail');
@$mail->@$mail->send('there@somewhere.com', $hdrs, $body);

?>
```

send_file.html

```
<form action="send_attach.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <table width="35%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="6">
    <tr class="style14">
      <td width="16%">Name <span class="style8">*</span></td>
      <td width="84%"><input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" for='name'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="style14">
      <td>Email <span class="style8">*</span></td>
      <td> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" for='email' placeholder="Email"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="style14">
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td> <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" for='phone' maxlength="10" placeholder="Numbers Only"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="style14">
      <td valign="top">Employment <br />
        Eligibility <span class="style8">*</span></td>
      <td valign="middle">
    <select name="work" class="style14" id="work">
          <option selected="selected">--- select option ---</option>
          <option>a</option>
          <option>b</option>
          <option>c`enter code here`</option>
        </select>      </td>
    </tr>`enter code here`
    <tr class="style14">
      <td>Experience<br />
Summary <span class="style8">*</span></td>
      <td valign="middle"><textarea name="summary" cols="35" rows="2" id="summary" placeholder="Experience Summary"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="style14">Resume<span class="style8"> * </span></td>
      <td><label>
        <input name="attachment" type="file" for='resume_uploaded_file'>
      </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
      <input type="submit" name="btn_get" id="btn_get" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you've uploaded the file to the filesystem in the example you provided.  You need to process the upload from the form POST, put the file on the filesystem, and then make sure you are referencing it correctly when you add it.  /file looks at the root of the server, not of the web server where your website is.

If you do a `file_exists('/studylink.txt')`

...My guess is the file does not exist.